# why is await not working in the second syntax?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

the following code results into the expected output

```js
function toppings_choice() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(console.log("which topping would you love?"));
      reject("not working");
    }, 3000);
  });
}

async function kitchen() {
  console.log("A");
  console.log("B");
  console.log("C");

  await toppings_choice();

  console.log("D");
  console.log("E");
}

kitchen();
```

```css
/* Stackoverflow: show only console */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

output:
A
B
C
which topping would you love?
D
E

but for some reason await in the following syntax does not work

```js
async function toppingChoice() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (true) {
      return console.log("which topping would you love?");
    } else {
      throw "not working";
    }
  }, 3000);
}

async function kitchenTwo() {
  console.log("A");
  console.log("B");
  console.log("C");

  await toppingChoice();

  console.log("D");
  console.log("E");
}

kitchenTwo();
```

```css
/* Stackoverflow: show only console */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

output:
A
B
C
D
E
which topping would you love?

both functions return a promise, so why is the await keyword working in the first code and indeed stopped the code until the promise was resolved but did not work in the second code?

I need to know if I could use the syntactic sugar of sync/await without having to use the promise constructor

Comment: Why would the second one do anything *else*?

Comment: The `return` inside the `setTimeout()` callback will not do anything useful.

Comment: there's no promise to await

Comment: because promises aren't magic. They don't just take the existing code and determine when it should resolve, you need to directly code that. By not returning anything at all, you've effectively created a promise that will instantly resolve

Answer (score 0):

> both functions return a promise

Not really, at least it's not the case for your `toppingChoice`.

The first one

```
function toppings_choice() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(console.log("which topping would you love?"));
      reject("not working");
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```

returns a promise which is fulfilled only after the timeout calls its callback.

The second

```
async function toppingChoice() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (true) {
      return console.log("which topping would you love?");
    } else {
      throw "not working";
    }
  }, 3000);
}
```

doesn't return anything in explicit way (no `return`) which makes it implicitely return a fulfilled promise with `undefined` value. When this promise is awaited, it doesn't even make the execution wait for anything. It's only 3000,s later when the timeout callback is called.

Note that adding `return` here

```
async function toppingChoice() {
  return setTimeout(() => { ...
```

won't help much as the result of `setTimeout` is not meant to be awaited (it's the timer id, a number).

> I need to know if I could use the syntactic sugar of sync/await without having to use the promise constructor

You can, assuming you run your code in node. Node has two versions of the `setTimeout`, [the old one, compatible with the browser API and an new one that returns a promise](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your 2nd approach is, that you return a `Promise` (since all function with the `async` keyword do that), but that promise immediately resolves (or better: a completed `Promise` is returned), therefore the program continues to run and exits before the callback specified for `setTimeout()` is scheduled to run on the event loop.

If you were to wait longer than 3 seconds before exiting the program you could observe that the callback actually gets invoked:

```js
async function toppingChoice() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (true) {
      return console.log("which topping would you love?");
    } else {
      throw "not working";
    }
  }, 3000);
}

async function kitchenTwo() {
  console.log("A");
  console.log("B");
  console.log("C");

  await toppingChoice();
  console.log("D");
  console.log("E");

  // wait before exiting the program so the callback set by setTimeout() gets to run
  await waitForMs(5000);
}

kitchenTwo();

function waitForMs(milliseconds){
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(), milliseconds));
}
```

```css
/* Stackoverflow: show only console */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

To really understand how this works you need an understanding of the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop) in JavaScript and you need to understand that behind a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is actually a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) but all of that is too much to go into detail here. Please have a look at the referenced resources.